# Makefile always compile no mater new or old

Tags: makefile

The following is my Makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
CLANG   = clang  
FLAGS   = -Wall -ggdb  
CFLAGS  = -g -fsanitize=address    
target  = doublefree usefree     
.PHONY: all clean  
all : $(target)  
% : %.c  
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $(addsuffix -gcc,$@) $<  
    $(CLANG) $(CFLAGS) -o $(addsuffix -clang,$@) $<  
clean :   
    $(foreach var,$(target),rm -f $(addsuffix -gcc,$(var)) $(addsuffix -clang,$(var)))
target : prerequisites model
```

When I make all, it always compile my file in the $(target) list, no matter the file is new or old! Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule:

```
%: %.c
    ...
```

So when Make must build `foo`, it believes that this rule will suffice. But look at the commands:

```
% : %.c  
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $(addsuffix -gcc,$@) $<  
    $(CLANG) $(CFLAGS) -o $(addsuffix -clang,$@) $<
```

This rule does *not* build `foo`; it builds `foo-gcc` and `foo-clang`. So the next time you run Make, Make sees that the needed `foo` does not exist and attempts to build it-- using that rule again.

**EDIT:**

I recommend this:

```
targets  = doublefree usefree 
all : $(addsuffix -gcc, $(targets)) $(addsuffix -clang,$(targets))

%-gcc : %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<  

%-clang : %.c
    $(CLANG) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Does make check whether the *.c is modified ?  Can you show me the check about whether the command should be executed!  Thank you in advance